# How to combine preference and CardView

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, listpreference

I am trying to make a setting menu with cardView and Preference, but I am not sure how to combine these two... Here's the screenshot and I want to move the ListPreference and PreferenceScreen entries into the setting cardView above.
Here's the preference.xml  The layout/setting_group is a cardview

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:layout="@layout/setting_title_top"
    android:title = "Padding" />
<PreferenceScreen
    android:layout="@layout/setting_group">
</PreferenceScreen>
<ListPreference
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout="@layout/setting_menu"
    android:dialogTitle = "title one"
    android:key = "key_1"
    android:title = "ListPreference"
    android:summary = "Summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListPreference>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:layout="@layout/setting_menu"
    android:key="Key two"
    android:summary="Summary"
    android:title="PreferenceScreen" />
<PreferenceScreen
    android:layout="@layout/setting_title"
    android:title = "Another Setting" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PreferenceScreen is a container, you are opening and closing him with noting inside.

You can create preferences like that:

```
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">




   <EditTextPreference
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:defaultValue="@string/default_value" <!--The initial state of the preference -->
    android:key="@string/pref_key" <!-- The key for retrieve the preference -->
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_title" />  <!-- The title who is showing above the preference -->


 </PreferenceScreen>
```

Edit: Create a xml file to with the layout of your preferences and create and Activity, example:

```
 public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
    implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_key))); // Is deprecated, but still a good option to no need change the values manually.


}

private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    onPreferenceChange(preference, PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
            .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));

}


@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
    String stringValue = value.toString();
    preference.setSummary(stringValue);



    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, I tried to paste my ListPreference Code into the preferenceScreen with "@layout/setting_group", but nothing shows up. How do you insert a preference into a cardview?

Comment: Why you need a card view ? The preference screen use the guidelines of google material design, just create a PreferenceScreen and put the fields that you need inside it, don't need another container.

Comment: I want to make a setting menu that looks like android's original menu... I need to customize the component to make the UI looks better

Comment: Thanks for the update... By the way, do you now how to get rid of the border around the ListPreference entry? or maybe just have the button line border

Comment: I think you will need to create a class that extend the ListPreference and override the layout resource, i don't remember if change background work for this